# Scheduled Sync Jobs in cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to run a nightly sync job triggers a private HTTP function which pulls data from an API and pushes it into my Firestore database but im struggling to get my function for run for long enough. In its current state it seems to only run for between 10-15 mins eventhough I have the timeout set to 3600 secs. I have tried changing the memory and CPU allocations which yield the same result. This is my deploy function:

```
exports.userdatasync= onRequest(
  {
    region: ["europe-west1"],
    timeoutSeconds: 3600,
    memory: "4GiB",
    cpu: 2,
    maxInstances: 15,
  },
  (req: any, res: any) => {
    userDataSync(req);
    res.status(200).send();
  }
);
```

Are there other limits I may be hitting that causes my function to just die halfway through? I cant find very much documentation on setting up a function like this so maybe its just not meant to be?

Have tried changing timeout, memory and CPU configs. Have also tried swapping between v1 and v2 functions.

Comment: Firstly, we can't see inside userDataSync, so we don't know what this function actually does.  Secondly, you're almost certainly not handling promises correctly.  You should only send a response after all async work is fully complete, otherwise the work might not complete at all.

Comment: Just triple checking all of my promise handling now, but if that were the fault wouldnt it just not work at all instead of syncing 150/400 of my users and consistently die around the 10-15 min mark?

Comment: The behavior is not going to be well-defined if you aren't handling promises correctly.

Comment: I had commented out the resolve on my first level promise by accident...fixed that and now working thank you